# ZF2: How to attach module specific listener for dispatch.error

Tags: php, events, zend-framework2

Is there a way I can attach an event listener for the event `dispatch.error` in Zend Framework 2, where that listener will only be attached to an EventManager related to the Module.php?

I have achieved this by attaching listener for `dispatch` to the global SharedManager and passing the current Module.php's namespace as first param. It works beautifully, but does NOT work, when I try the same for `dispatch.error`.

Here's an example in Module.php:

```
public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
{
    $sharedManager  = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    $sharedManager->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function($e) {
        exit('IT WORKS');
    });
    $sharedManager->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch.error', function($e) {
        exit('IT DOES NOT WORK');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is working for dispatch but not dispatch.error is that the dispatch event gets triggered from within in the controller (see Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController::dispatch)

Because you extend this class with your own namespaced controller, it is possible to associate the event with that namespace.

However, the dispatch.error event may be triggered before a controller (and with it the context of your namespace) is ever loaded. This happens according to more than one condition in Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.

In order to customize the way dispatch.error is handled, you will likely need to write a custom listener for that event, or even write your own DispatchListener (though I'd recommend against that). You can then perhaps look at the routeMatch to figure out what you'd like to do next. If you're using the ModuleRouteListener this could be pretty easy.

Comment: Could you please describe a little more? I have the same issue and have no idea how to figure it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572417/zf2-error-handling-for-a-specific-module-only